# why foreach make duplicate at last row?

Tags: php

The `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` have 4 rows but in database there are 4 + 1 duplicate from last row

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item1){
    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO `t_rinci_jual_tunai` (`kd_operasional`, `kd_barang`, `jumlah`, `harga_satuan`, `kd_satuan`) VALUES ('2', '" . $item1["kd_barang"] . "', '" . $item1["quantity"] . "', '" . $item1["harga_patokan"] . "', '505')";
    $insert= mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css">
</head>
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left;"><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:left;"><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Total</strong></th>
<th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>

<?php
session_start();
require_once("Connecting.php");
 if (isset($_GET['enter']) && ($_SESSION["cart_item"])){    
      echo "enter ada"; 
            switch ($_GET["enter"]){
                case "enter";



                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item1){



                        $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO `t_rinci_jual_tunai` (`kd_operasional`, `kd_barang`, `jumlah`, `harga_satuan`, `kd_satuan`) VALUES ('2', '" . $item1["kd_barang"] . "', '" . $item1["quantity"] . "', '" . $item1["harga_patokan"] . "', '505')";
                    $insert= mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert);

                ?>  <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><strong><?php echo $item1['name']; ?></strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><?php echo $item1["kd_barang"]; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><?php echo $item1["quantity"]; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><?php echo "$".$item1["harga_patokan"]; ?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php   

                    }

                    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}       
            break; } 
            } else {
                echo "enter tidak ada ";

            }

?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `for` (with invalid syntax)? or `foreach()`?

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: Okay with the update output `$item1` in your loop and prior `print_r($_SESSION["cart_item"])`;

Comment: sorry the problem i mean is from foreach not "for" it's miss type

Comment: well regardless... I'm not retracting my vote.

Comment: i dont care with vote i just want solution

Comment: We need more information to help you.

Comment: what is it chris85? whole script ?

Comment: There is no reason that the `foreach` loop you show creates duplicate entries. Are you sure that there were only 4 entries in the array? Does this duplication happen every time? Are you sure the last entry wasn't already in the database before the script ran? Are there other `INSERT` statements near this loop? BTW, you should use parameterized queries, creating an SQL query from string concatenation is dangerous.

Comment: 1.i sure there are only for in seasson couse i make pint_r the seasson 2. this happen every time 3. i delete all row in database 4. it the only one insert statement i have

Comment: The `foreach` is fine but right after it you run the last query generated in `$sqlinsert` again: *`if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";`* As a general advice, don't mix the logic (the PHP code) with the presentation (the HTML).

Comment: thanks axiac its done now

Comment: Axiac has pointed out the problem, just as on addon @Aris please do use php transaction (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) to check such multiple query execution & if($insert_id) for single  insert (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreach instead of for:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item1) { ... }
```